# Query not executing and not getting the reults

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 const string keyword = "manoj";
        rsp.DataSource = company.GetCompanySearch(keyword);
        rsp.DataBind();
    using (var context = huntableEntities.GetEntitiesWithNoLock())
    {
        IEnumerable<Company> query = context.Companies.ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            keyword = keyword.ToLower();
            query =  query.Where(u=>u.CompanyName.Contains(keyword)
                || u.EmailAdress.Contains(keyword)
                ||u.MasterCountry.Description.Contains(keyword)
                ||u.MasterIndustry.Description.Contains(keyword)
                ||u.CompanyDescription.Contains(keyword)
                ||u.CompanyHeading.Contains(keyword));
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Query not getting the results. The database has 27 records with name manoj. 
The inner exception is null for this

Comment: What line is throwing the exception ?

Comment: Inner exception is null? So there was an exception?

Answer (score 0):

It should work as expected if you change the line `IEnumerable<Company> query = ...` to

```
var query = context.Companies;
```

This turns `query` into an `IQueryable<Company>`, of which the expression will be extended by the line `query =  query.Where(...`. This will be done in a way that the `Contains` expressions will be translated into SQL (`LIKE`).

In your current code you fetch all Companies into memory and the `Contains` is executed by linq-to-objects. This is case-sensitive, the reason why I think you did not get any matches. The SQL is probably case-insensitive. That depends on the collation of your database.